# How to make the code loop?

Tags: python, loops

I want this slot machine game code to loop so i can play it without opening and closing. i'm a beginner so i might have something left out. i have tried to make it work for about an hour now and i have tried lot of solutionsm but they didnt work

```
import random
global Cash
global CashLose
global CashWin



Cash = 50
CashLose = 15
CashWin = 20

def SlotMachine ():
    global Cash
    global CashLose
    global RandomNumber
    global UserNumber  

spin = raw_input (" Press y to spin a slot ")
RandomNumber = random.randrange(1, 7, 1)
if spin == "y":
        Cash = Cash - CashLose
        UserNumber = raw_input (" pick a number 1-7 ")
        print " SPINNING... "
if RandomNumber == UserNumber:
        print " You WIn! 20 Dollars Credited "
        Cash = Cash + CashWin
        print "Cash Ammount" +str(Cash)

else:
        print " you lost money, no win! "
        print " please spin again! "
        print "Cash Ammount" +str(Cash)
```

Comment: _"i have tried lot of solutionsm but they didnt work"_. Show us a couple.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a clue, Put it in appropriate place

```
while True:

    spin = raw_input(" Press y to spin a slot or n to exit")
    if spin == "n":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is really, really unpythonic. In python there is no need to declare a variable before assigning a value to it.

A good way to do what you want would be:

```
import random

Cash = 50
CashLose = 15
CashWin = 20

while True:
    spin = raw_input (" Press y to spin a slot ")
    RandomNumber = random.randrange(1, 7, 1)
    if spin in ['y', 'Y']:
        Cash = Cash - CashLose
        UserNumber = raw_input(" pick a number 1-7 ")
        print " SPINNING... "
        if RandomNumber == UserNumber:
            print " You WIn! 20 Dollars Credited "
            Cash = Cash + CashWin
            print "Cash Ammount", Cash
        else:
            print " you lost money, no win! "
            print " please spin again! "
            print "Cash Ammount", Cash
```

Also maybe you should consider reading a python tutorial and [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

Using itzmeontv suggestion, you can make the code loop like this:

```
import random

Cash = 50
CashLose = 15
CashWin = 20

while True:

    spin = raw_input(" Press y to spin a slot or n to exit ")
    if spin == "n":
        break

    RandomNumber = random.randrange(1, 7, 1)    

    Cash = Cash - CashLose
    UserNumber = raw_input (" pick a number 1-7 ")
    print " SPINNING... "

    if RandomNumber == UserNumber:
            print " You WIn! 20 Dollars Credited "
            Cash = Cash + CashWin
            print "Cash Ammount" +str(Cash)

    else:
            print " you lost money, no win! "
            print " please spin again! "
            print "Cash Ammount " +str(Cash)
```